# Is it possible to code split (webpack) with static single page app? (React/React-router)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, github-pages, webpack-2

I am aware of server side isomorphic rendering, but I currently have a site hosted on github pages so server-side isn't possible (or is it?).

I've been doing some research and found various comments saying that it is possible, but I'm looking for confirmation, and perhaps a more detailed explanation of how code-splitting is possible with a static single page app. My bundle.js file is currently 500+kb, and I'd like to see how I can reduce load-time, especially as I continue adding features.

Comment: According to react-router [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting) (at bottom of the page), they mention gave up on code-splitting with server rendering. However, code-splitting is possible, they recommend webpack [bundle loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/bundle-loader)

Comment: Correct, you can't use server rendering w/ github hosted pages, you would need own nodejs server for that

Answer (score 0):

If I recall with react-router you can define a parameter in your Route component getComponent(), and use System.import to load your dependencies e.g.

```
{
     path: '/',
     getComponent(location, cb) {
       System.import('path/Component').then(loadRoute(cb)).catch(errorLoading);
     }
```

Comment: does this method allow for code splitting with a single page app?